# Run Web Test using Visual Studio 2017 Based on chrome

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to add a Web Test and I found that visual studio has the ability to record steps\flow using internet explorer and execute it.

> The problem is that when I run the test, it just do something and displays **"Pass"** as a result without opening the browser so I don't able to see the process on the browser.

Is there an option to see the full process on the browser?

Additionally, is there an option to record a web test steps using chrome or edge? I saw an option to do it only with IE11.

Comment: what is option you have on IE11?

Comment: @Asif.Ali https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/load-test/run-performance-tests-app-before-release

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a solution to record your Web Test by another browser like chrome in Visual Studio, but you can use Fiddler to capture the HTTP(s) requests by any browser you want to do your tests. Then, export the captured requests as a Visual Studio Web Test. After recording the requests by Fiddler, Go to File->Export Sessions-> All Sessions, "Select Export Format" window will appear, then choose "Visual Studio Web Test" from the dropdown list.

More information:
https://trailheadtechnology.com/visual-studio-web-performance-tests-dynamically-looping-over-nested-data

I hope it'll be useful :)